# SimpleMembership seed configuration troubles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to set up simplemembership for ASP.NET MVC4 application

I try to seed configuration, I was able to create Roles but not users I get an error saying 
You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call ... 
this is my code for configuration

I used SeedSimple example

```
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SeedSimple.Models.UsersContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(SeedSimple.Models.UsersContext context)
        {
            if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection",
                    "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

                var roles = new SimpleRoleProvider(Roles.Provider);

                var membership = new SimpleMembershipProvider(Membership.Provider);

                //ADING ROLES
                if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin")) roles.CreateRole("Admin");


                //CREATE USER 
                if (membership.GetUser("administrateur", false) == null) membership.CreateUserAndAccount("administrateur", "sm");

                //USER TO ROLE
                if (!roles.GetRolesForUser("administrateur").Contains("Admin"))
                {
                    roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "administrateur" }, new[] { "admin" });
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: In which line do you get this error? Can you give some more information?

Comment: Here exactly : if (membership.GetUser("administrateur", false) == null) membership.CreateUserAndAccount("administrateur", "sm");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something and it worked like a sharm, I used this instead of the first while creating users

```
if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("administrateur"))
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
                    "administrateur",
                    "test",
                    new { Email = "mail@mail.com" },
                    false
                );
            }
```

Now, I can't assign users to roles I get this error  : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "crm_db", table "db.Users", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.